# Typesetting guitar chord diagrams in a songbook

Tags: positioning, music

I am writing a songbook and I would like to insert guitar chord diagrams in the appropriate positions above the lyrics of each verse. I have found the `musixguit` package capable of drawing nice diagrams which I would like to include in my songbook (showing fret numbering for barre chords and possibly tabular notation of the chord) but I am not able to position them in accordance with the lyrics.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixguit}
\begin{document}
\raiseguitar {14}
\NOtes\guitar {Cm $^7$}{2}x-----\gbarre1\gdot33\gdot52
\guitar G{}o-----\gbarre3\gdot25\gdot35\gdot44\en
*Lyrics of the first *verse...
\end{document}
```

How to place the diagrams above their intended positions (denoted by asterisks)? Would it be possible to define a new command for in-line insertion of predefined chords into the appropriate positions in lyrics like in the following example?

```
\chord{Cm7}Lyrics of the first \chord{G}verse...
```

Thank you.

Comment: It seems the word above which there's a chord should be the second argument of the `\chord` command.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I didn't really think of adding any more parameters to the command. They are, however, centered above the position (instead of starting there with their left edge) and are drown over previous chords if two diagrams are placed too close to each other (instead of making a horizontal spacing in the lyrics). Could you please think of any correction, preferably to be inserted right into the lyrics?

Comment: I've just taken a look at the documentation (but iI don't speak German…); in the example on page 2, the chord is not really centred w.r.t. the word below. There's only a slight shifting from the left side of the word, and there doesn't seem to be any parameter that can change that. If you really want to have the vertical alignment on the left side of the word, you can try with the `\stackon` command from the `stackengine` package.

Comment: You are using the `musixgui` extension from `musixtex` (which is loaded by the `musixguit` package). I suggest you have a look at [`gchords`](http://ctan.org/pkg/gchords) instead – maybe in combination with [`guitar`](http://ctan.org/pkg/guitar).

Comment: `musixgui` is only meant for using chord diagrams over music staffs…

Comment: Thank you both for suggestions. I was originally considering the `gchords` and `songs` packages but neither of them seems to support barre chords (with the thick line drawn by `musixguit` in my two example chords). Although `songs` is capable of annotating each string with a number below the diagram. I might stick to `songs` later on if all my attempts with `musixguit` fail but I pin my hopes on Bernard's suggestion with `stackengine` for now.

Comment: Also, with `gchords` it seems impossible to draw a diagram of a chord held on higher frets. This chord for example: `\newcommand{\Bsus}{\chord{}{o,p9,p9,p8,o,o}{Bsus4(+3)}}` produces `LaTeX
 Error: Bad \line or \vector argument.` on the line where `\Bsus` is used in the document.

Comment: Is it possible to hide the chord diagram and use only the letter of the cord?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The chords only have to be defined via `\guitarchord` once, and can be reutilized as needed. Rather that using `\raiseguitar` to set the vertical position, I use `\setstackgap{L}{<baselinekip of stack>}` to do so.

EDITED to address deficiencies noted by OP.  Macros to use include

```
\guitarchord\<chordname>{<chord-definition>}
```

and

```
\showchord [<short entry text>]{\<chordname>}
```

where the optional argument is used if the chord text is shorter than the chord width.  Note two lengths specified in the MWE that allow adjustments in alignment and minimum chord spacing.

RE-EDITED to provide optional syntax that some may find preferable:

```
\chordline{\<chordname>}{<text>}
```

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixguit,stackengine}
\def\chordalign{\dimexpr2.2ex}% 2.2ex sets alignment of chord
\def\chordminwidth{\dimexpr6.5ex}% 6.5ex provides min. hskip for optional argument
\newcommand\guitarchord[2]{%
  \savestack#1{\kern\chordalign\NOtes\guitar #2\en}
}
\newcommand\showchord[2][\relax]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\def\tmpuaw{T}\else\def\tmpuaw{F}\fi%
  \stackengine{\Lstackgap}{#1}{%
    \makebox[0ex][l]{#2}\kern\chordminwidth}{O}{l}{F}{\tmpuaw}{L}%
}
\newcommand\chordline[2]{\setbox0=\hbox{#2}%
  \ifdim\wd0>\chordminwidth\showchord{#1}#2\else\showchord[#2]{#1}\fi%
}
\raiseguitar {0}
\setstackgap{L}{2.7\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\guitarchord\Cm{{Cm $^7$}{2}x-----\gbarre1\gdot33\gdot52}
\guitarchord\GM{G{}o-----\gbarre3\gdot25\gdot35\gdot44}
\showchord[Ly-]{\Cm} \showchord{\GM}rics of the first 
  \showchord[of 2]{\Cm} \showchord{\GM}verses ...

Alternative syntax:

\chordline{\Cm}{Ly-}
\chordline{\GM}{rics of the first}
\chordline{\Cm}{of 2}
\chordline{\GM}{verses ...}
\end{document}
```

[image]

While I don't recommend it because of potential danger, the OP followed up asking if the `#` character (and things like parentheses) could be incorporated into chord names.  To do so, I make `#` catcode 11, and employ a lot of `\csname` nomenclature.

Here is such a version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixguit,stackengine}
\def\chordalign{\dimexpr2.2ex}% 2.2ex sets alignment of chord
\def\chordminwidth{\dimexpr9ex}% 6.5ex provides min. hskip for optional argument
\newcommand\guitarchord[2]{%
  \expandafter\savestack\expandafter{\csname #1\endcsname}{%
    \kern\chordalign\NOtes\guitar #2\en}
}
\newcommand\showchord[2][\relax]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\def\tmpuaw{T}\else\def\tmpuaw{F}\fi%
  \stackengine{\Lstackgap}{#1}{%
    \makebox[0ex][l]{\csname #2\endcsname}\kern\chordminwidth}%
    {O}{l}{F}{\tmpuaw}{L}%
}
\newcommand\chordline[2]{\setbox0=\hbox{#2}%
  \ifdim\wd0>\chordminwidth\relax\showchord{#1}#2\else
    \showchord[#2]{#1}\fi%
}
\raiseguitar {0}
\setstackgap{L}{2.7\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\catcode`#=11
\guitarchord{F#m7(add4)}{{F$\sharp$m7(add4)$^7$}{2}x-----\gbarre1\gdot33\gdot52}
\guitarchord{GM}{G{}o-----\gbarre3\gdot25\gdot35\gdot44}
\showchord[Ly-]{F#m7(add4)} \showchord{GM}rics of the first 
  \showchord[of 2]{F#m7(add4)} \showchord{GM}verses ...

Alternative syntax:

\chordline{F#m7(add4)}{Ly-}
\chordline{GM}{rics of the first}
\chordline{F#m7(add4)}{of 2}
\chordline{GM}{verses ...}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This was a nice answer! However, I struggle with the right positioning of the diagrams. They should be aligned to left, not center, starting at the position where they are placed. Also, they should not overflow other diagrams if they appear too close to them but rather shift the lyrics to the right, widening the space between the two words or syllables. It is also sometimes needed to specify only a syllable (or even a one-character space) which the chord should be fixed to. Like e.g. `\tclap[0pt]{\Cm}{Ly}\tclap[0pt]{\G}{rics} of the first (...)`

Comment: I have now fixed the alignment issue by updating some definitions from `musixgui.tex` file (which is rather an ugly hack than a solution). Namely:
`\def\guitar#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{\zchar\r@gu{\raise\Interligne\rlap{#1}%
  \mxsps\rlap\sixt@@n\rlap{\d@c#3\d@c#4\d@c#5\d@c#6\d@c#7\d@c#8}%
  \lower\Internote\llap{\eightbf#2\kern\s@v@n\guitar@dim}}}`,
`\def\gbarre#1{\zchar\r@gu{\n@v#1\advance\n@v\m@ne
  \raise\n@v\guitar@dim\rlap{\mxsps\char18}}}`
and
`\def\gdot#1#2{\zchar\r@gu{\n@v#2\advance\n@v\m@ne\kern\guitar@dim
  \kernm#1\guitar@dim\raise\n@v\guitar@dim\llap{\mxsps\char17}}}`.

Comment: But the diagram overlapping, as can be shown using `\frame{\guitar{...}}`, is caused by the diagram having no width and this is something I cannot fix on my own.

Comment: @Kyselejsyreček There are 3 macros in the `stackengine` package for top lapping, `\tllap`, `\tclap`, and `\trlap`, depending on which alignment is desired (l,c,r).

Comment: Yes, I have tried all three of them but they have no effect on the diagram placement.

Comment: @Kyselejsyreček There is no *automatic* way, with this method, to categorically prevent overlap;  that said, one can manually change the lapping (if that is acceptable).  On the other hand, if the chord is wider than the associated text, one can, instead of a top lap command, use `\stackon[gap]{text}{<Chord Macro>}` and space will be introduced after the text.  In the preamble, select proper alignment (default centered) with `\renewcommand\stackalignment{<l, c, or r>}`

Comment: @Kyselejsyreček I see the issue is that the chords are created with 0 width.  One could arbitrarily reassign their width to a non-zero value.  I will try to revise my MWE a bit.

Comment: Yes, I have tried even using `\stackon` and this led me to the observation that the chord diagram has no width, as can be seen with `\stackon{Ly}{\frame{\notes\guitar {Cm $^7$}{2}x-----\gbarre1\gdot33\gdot52\en}}`. Thus, no space around the lyrics is introduced and all too wide neighbouring diagrams overlap.

Comment: @Kyselejsyreček Please see my revision

Comment: This was a really nice fix. Maybe something like wrapping the succeeding lyrics in a box with minimal width set, ending the box with a new chord diagram or end of line, whichever comes first, would not require the lyrics an additional parameter.
There's only one last problem with the chord labeling - whenever the label is too long and exceeds the diagram, the reserved space for the diagram should adapt to the length of the diagram label (try with Cm7sus4 etc.). One could bypass the `\guitar` macro, place the text above the diagram and determine its length.
Thank you for you effort anyway!

Comment: @Kyselejsyreček Please see the alternative syntax my MWE now provides.

Comment: Yes! `\chordline` syntax might be very handy in some songs. Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: @Steen No, sorry, still the issue with too long chord names was not addressed. Consider Cm7 being named F#m7(add4) for example. By the way, there should be curly brackets around `#1` in `\guitarchord`. Is there any way of saving a chord like F#m7(add4) using its name with the # character or is the use of sharp chords restricted to replacing the # with e.g. x?

Comment: @Kyselejsyreček Please see the supplement to my answer for a very dangerous approach to what you ask.  The `#` character is special to LaTeX, and setting it `\catcode 11` is frought with danger, I think.

Comment: @Kyselejsyreček I would just point out as a reminder that you can have all the fancy text in the definition of the chord (2nd argument of `\guitarchord`) without utilizing that same text in the naming of the chord macro (1st argument of `\guitarchord`).  Note I updated answer to reflect use of `$\sharp$`.

Answer (score 5):

A combination of the [`guitarchordschemes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/guitarchordschemes) package (needs v0.7) for creating the chord diagrams and the [`leadsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/leadsheets) package for placing the chords:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% the `chords' library of the leadsheets package provides the convenient
% \chord macro; we don't any other functionality  of said package so we
% use the `chords' option:
\usepackage{leadsheets}
% no parsing of the chord input:
\setleadsheets{chord-cs=}

\usepackage{guitarchordschemes}
% guitarchordschemes setup:
\setchordscheme{
  tuning = {,,,,,} ,
  chord-frets = 4 ,
  rotate = -90 ,
  x-unit = 1.5mm , y-unit = 2mm ,
  finger-radius = .25 ,
  line-width = .6pt ,
  restrict-bounding-box ,
  position-format+ = \footnotesize ,
  chord-name-cs = \chordname ,
  name-distance = 0pt
}

\newcommand\minorsevenAtype[2]{%
  \chordscheme[
    name = #1 ,
    position = #2 ,
    finger = {2/2,3/4} ,
    barre = {1/1-5} ,
    mute = {6}
  ]%
}

\newcommand\minorsevenEtype[2]{%
  \chordscheme[
    name = #1 ,
    position = #2 ,
    finger = {1/6} ,
    barre = {1/2-4} ,
    mute = {1,5}
  ]%
}

\newcommand\majorEtype[2]{%
  \chordscheme[
    name = #1 ,
    position = #2 ,
    finger = {2/3,3/4,3/5} ,
    barre = {1/1-6}
  ]%
}

\newcommand\majorAtype[2]{%
  \chordscheme[
    name = #1 ,
    position = #2 ,
    finger = {3/2,3/3,3/4} ,
    barre = {1/1-5} ,
    mute = 6
  ]%
}

\newcommand\cminorseven{\minorsevenAtype{Cmi7}{III}}
\newcommand\fminorseven{\minorsevenEtype{Fmi7}{I}}
\newcommand\gmajor{\majorEtype{Gma}{III}}
\newcommand\ebmajor{\majorAtype{Ebma}{VI}}

\begin{document}

\chord{\cminorseven}Text and text and \chord{\ebmajor}more text and
\chord{\gmajor}more text and even \chord{\fminorseven}more text

\end{document}
```