# Stylize GChords?

Tags: packages

Is it possible to modify the visuals of GChords easily? Draw lines like in `tikz`, and color frets?

If not, how hard would it be to create a command like `\chord` that builds the diagram up using `tikz` then one could modify the diagram in a `tikz` environment(or through custom commands) to do various things?

e.g.,

```
\bar{\chord{1,1,1,2,2,3}}{2,4}
```

`\bar` creates a bar visual between frets 2 and 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not familiar with GChords and no MWE was provided by the OP, so I have no idea if this will provide a suitable alternative or not...Starting with this question, [Typesetting guitar chord diagrams in a songbook](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324828/typesetting-guitar-chord-diagrams-in-a-songbook), one can add color to the various parts of it, to display guitar chords.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixguit,stackengine,xcolor}
\def\chordalign{\dimexpr2.2ex}% 2.2ex sets alignment of chord
\def\chordminwidth{\dimexpr6.5ex}% 6.5ex provides min. hskip for optional argument
\newcommand\guitarchord[2]{%
  \savestack#1{\kern\chordalign\NOtes\guitar #2\en}
}
\newcommand\showchord[2][\relax]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\def\tmpuaw{T}\else\def\tmpuaw{F}\fi%
  \stackengine{\Lstackgap}{#1}{%
    \makebox[0ex][l]{#2}\kern\chordminwidth}{O}{l}{F}{\tmpuaw}{L}%
    \hspace{1.2cm}%
}

\raiseguitar {0}
\setstackgap{L}{2.7\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\guitarchord\Cm{{Cm $^7$}{2}x-----\gbarre1\gdot33\gdot52}
\guitarchord\GM{G{}o-----\gbarre3\gdot25\gdot35\gdot44}


\color{cyan}\guitarchord\Cm{{\color{black}Cm $^7$}{\color{black}2}
  x-----\color{green}\gbarre1\color{red}\gdot33\gdot52}
\showchord{\Cm}
\end{document}
```

[image]