# Draw the clamp on guitar chord diagram with GChords

Tags: music

I'm trying to generate guitar chords, everything is fine until I arrived to Do#m. Here is my snippet:

```
\begin{document}
\mediumchords
\chords{
  \chord{4}{x,f1p1,f3p3,f4p3,f2p2,f1p1}{Do\#m (C\#m)}
}
\end{document}
```

Which outputs:

[image: latex output]

on this case, ideally, a bar should go from the `finger 1 string 1` to `finger 1 string 5`.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

`gchords` doesn't have any functionality to distinguish barre chords. It looks like it's possible with `musixguit` but the documentation is in German only. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372496/stylize-gchords) includes an example of producing a chord with the barre notated although it's not a partial barre as requested and I'm unsure if any existing package will do this out of the box. That said, it's probably a good starting point for being able to get the desired result.

**Edit**: Doing a bit more digging, it looks like the best package for the job is [`chordbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chordbox) which does support partial barres. A good starting place for seeing what other options are available is [here](https://ctan.org/topic/chords?lang=en).

Comment: `musixguit` only uses the chord schemes from the `musixtex` package (and is not developed any more). `guitarchordschemes` can probably do what the OP wants...

Comment: It looks like `guitarchordschemes` does do the job except that it produces horizontal chord charts rather than vertical (which are the norm).

Comment: Have a look at this answer of mine then https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325547/

Comment: BTW `guitarchordschemes` was meant to produce chord charts and not diagrams in songbooks in the first place. The former are usually printed the way that you look on a fretboard, i.e., horizontal.